# Number of commuting diagrams obtained from four finite sets

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ be four finite sets.  Define a function $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ by saying $f(|A|,|B|,|C|,|D|)$ is the number of commuting squares involving the sets $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$.  That is, $f(|A|,|B|,|C|,|D|)$ is the cardinality of the set

$$\{(q,b,d,p) \mid qb=dp ,b \in \operatorname{Hom}(A,B), p \in \operatorname{Hom}(A,C), q \in \operatorname{Hom}(B,D), d \in \operatorname{Hom}(C,D)\}$$

Is there a nice formula for the function $f$?  I don't believe there is a nice short (polynomial) formula for $f$; if that is the case, I would like some basic understanding why.

Comment: Well, it is easy to show that it grows exponentially, so it cannot be a polynomial in $|A|$, $|B|$, $|C|$, and $|D|$.  But if you allow "polynomials" in which expressions involving $|A|$, $|B|$, $|C|$, and $|D|$ can appear in the exponents, it seems like it would probably be quite difficult to _prove_ that no such expression gives a formula for this function.